# Querying remote registry service on machine <IP Address> resulted in exception: Unable to change open service manager

Tags: windows, networking, azure-service-fabric, lan

My cluster Config file as follows
`

```
{
    "name": "SampleCluster",
    "clusterConfigurationVersion": "1.0.0",
    "apiVersion": "01-2017",
    "nodes": 
    [
        {
            "nodeName": "vm0",
            "iPAddress": "here is my VPS ip",
            "nodeTypeRef": "NodeType0",
            "faultDomain": "fd:/dc1/r0",
            "upgradeDomain": "UD0"
        },
        {
            "nodeName": "vm1",
            "iPAddress": "here is my another VPS ip",
            "nodeTypeRef": "NodeType0",
            "faultDomain": "fd:/dc1/r1",
            "upgradeDomain": "UD1"
        },
        {
            "nodeName": "vm2",
            "iPAddress": "here is my another VPS ip",
            "nodeTypeRef": "NodeType0",
            "faultDomain": "fd:/dc1/r2",
            "upgradeDomain": "UD2"
        }
    ],
    "properties": {
        "reliabilityLevel": "Bronze",
        "diagnosticsStore": 
        {
            "metadata":  "Please replace the diagnostics file share with an actual file share accessible from all cluster machines.",
            "dataDeletionAgeInDays": "7",
            "storeType": "FileShare",
            "IsEncrypted": "false",
            "connectionstring": "c:\\ProgramData\\SF\\DiagnosticsStore"
        },
        "nodeTypes": [
          {
            "name": "NodeType0",
            "clientConnectionEndpointPort": "19000",
            "clusterConnectionEndpointPort": "19001",
            "leaseDriverEndpointPort": "19002",
            "serviceConnectionEndpointPort": "19003",
            "httpGatewayEndpointPort": "19080",
            "reverseProxyEndpointPort": "19081",
            "applicationPorts": {
                "startPort": "20001",
                "endPort": "20031"
            },
            "isPrimary": true
          }
      ],
      "fabricSettings": [
        {
          "name": "Setup",
          "parameters": [
            {
                "name": "FabricDataRoot",
                "value": "C:\\ProgramData\\SF"
            },
            {
                "name": "FabricLogRoot",
                "value": "C:\\ProgramData\\SF\\Log"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

It is almost identical to standalone service fabric download demo file for untrusted cluster except my VPS ip. I enabled remote registry service.I ran the 
`\TestConfiguration.ps1 -ClusterConfigFilePath \ClusterConfig.Unsecure.MultiMachine.json` but i got the following error.

```
Unable to change open service manager handle because 5
    Unable to query service configuration because System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to change open service manager ha
    ndle because 5
       at System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.FabricDeployerServiceController.GetServiceStartupType(String machineName, String serv
    iceName)
    Querying remote registry service on machine <IP Address> resulted in exception: Unable to change open service manager
    handle because 5.
    Unable to change open service manager handle because 5
    Unable to query service configuration because System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to change open service manager ha
    ndle because 5
       at System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.FabricDeployerServiceController.GetServiceStartupType(String machineName, String serv
    iceName)
    Querying remote registry service on machine <Another IP Address> resulted in exception: Unable to change open service manager
    handle because 5.
    Best Practices Analyzer determined environment has an issue. Please see additional BPA log output in DeploymentTraces



LocalAdminPrivilege        : True
IsJsonValid                : True
IsCabValid                 :
RequiredPortsOpen          : True
RemoteRegistryAvailable    : False
FirewallAvailable          :
RpcCheckPassed             :
NoConflictingInstallations :
FabricInstallable          :
DataDrivesAvailable        :
Passed                     : False

Test Config failed with exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Best Practices Analyzer determined environment has
an issue. Please see additional BPA log output in DeploymentTraces folder.
   at System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.ThrowTerminatingError(ErrorRecord errorRecord)
```

I don't understand the problem.VPSs are not locally connected. All are public IP.I don't know, this may b an issue. how do I make virtual LAN among these VPS?Can anyone give me some direction about this error?Anyone helps me is greatly appreciated.
Edit: I used VM term insted of VPS.

Comment: `RemoteRegistryAvailable    : False` Follow the guide, open ports, start services etc.. mosy importantly ensure VMs can talk to each other! Create virtual switch in hyperv (or whatever) and configure host to have fixed ip, then configure guests to use this switch and set gateway and appropriate static IPs. Easiest way I found to enable network discovery  was to just open up `network` and click the yellow warning to enable!

Comment: How do i check VMs can talk to each other.Each VMs have public IP.I can ping from one another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I make this working. Actually all the nodes are in a network, i thought it wasn't. I enable file sharing. I try to access the shared file from the node where I ran configuration test to the all other nodes. I have to give the credentials of logins. And then it works like a charm.

Comment: I am new in ServiceFabric. Could you please provide an example, so that we can learn how have you given the credentials of logins.